# SQL Query - Multiple Joins on Same field

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys

I need assistance building this query where i need to select different values from same table but different Unique Keys.

To elaborate more ill provide the below example:

I have 2 tables:

> Issues (IssueID, AuthorID_FK, AssigedID_FK, ... )
>   Users (UserID, User_Label, ... )

Both **AuthorID_FK** & **AssigedID_FK** are linked to table **Users** and i need to get in the same query result the **User_Label** for both.

Can you please assist?

Thanks,

Comment: It will be helpful if you show your expected result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.IssueID, b.User_Label, c.User_Label FROM Issues a
INNER JOIN USERS b on a.AuthorID_FK = b.UserID
INNER JOIN USERS c on a.AssignedID_FK = c.UserID
```

something like that :) This should work in MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one should work too :)

```
SELECT IssueID, U.User_Label FROM Issues I
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID = I.AuthorID_FK

UNION

SELECT IssueID, U.User_Label FROM Issues I
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.UserID = I.AssigedID_FK
```

Answer (score 0):

Wont

```
SELECT a.IssueID, b.UserID 
FROM Issues a 
    JOIN Users b ON (a.AuthorID_FK=b.UserID OR a.AssignedID_FK = b.UserID)
```

work?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this

```
SELECT
    issues.IssueID,
    Authour.User_Label AS Author_Label,
    Assigned.User_Label AS Assigned_user_Label
FROM
    issues
    INNER JOIN users AS Authour ON Authour.UserID = issues.AuthorID_FK
    INNER JOIN users AS Assigned ON Assigned.UserID = issues.AssignedID_FK
```